# Can I change nodes hierarchy?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I would like to know, is there a chance to change hierarchy of nodes?

Something like setChildIndex in ActionScript3. I want to move one sprite above the other, after some action.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean the child-parent hierarchy (node tree) or the layering (making a sprite render on top of the other)

Comment: I believe I answered your question below. If you are looking for something else, please add more detail to your question so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the nodes zPosition with yourNode.zPosition = 0;
zPosition 0 will be behind zPosition 1, and so on. You can set it at any event point if the node is available.

Also, check the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html). It has a good explanation of setting many of a node's properties such as zPosition.